# How to handle clicks in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I currently have jQuery functions that use mouseenter and mouseleave. This currently gives me the desired effect where everything is returned to normal once the mouse leaves a div. I am trying to replicate this but instead using click, I was reading up about on() and off() but I do not think this can be used. Below is my code.

```
jQuery(".leftpara").hide();
jQuery(".rightpara").hide();
jQuery('#home-grid-one-two').mouseenter(function(){ 
$('#home-grid-two-one').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden' 
    });
$('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden' 
    });
$('#home-grid-two-three').hide();
$('#home-grid-three-three').hide();
jQuery(".leftpara").show();
jQuery(".rightpara").show();
jQuery(".ptagexp").hide();
        });
         jQuery('#home-grid-one-two').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#home-grid-two-one').css({
        'visibility': 'visible' 
    });
$('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'visibility': 'visible' 
    });
    $('#home-grid-three-two').show();
            $('#home-grid-two-one').show();
            $('#home-grid-three-one').show();
            $('#home-grid-two-three').show();
            $('#home-grid-three-three').show();
jQuery(".leftpara").hide();
jQuery(".rightpara").hide();
jQuery(".ptagexp").show();
```

HTML

```
<div id="home-grid-one-one" class="home-grid"> 
<div class="page" title="Page 2">
<p class="leftpara"> Some Text.</p>
</div>


<div id="home-grid-one-two" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 6">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p style="text-align: center;">Anthony &amp;
Thomas</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home-grid-one-three" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<p class="rightpara"> Some Text.</p>

</div>
<div id="home-grid-two-one" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 6">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p style="text-align: center;">Award winning</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home-grid-two-two" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 6">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Proven
to deliver</strong></p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home-grid-two-three" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 6">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p style="text-align: center;">Development
Process</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home-grid-three-one" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2"></div>
<div class="page" title="Page 2"></div>
<div id="home-grid-three-two" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 2">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<div class="page" title="Page 6">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p class="ptagexp" style="text-align: center;">Experience in
many markets</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="home-grid-three-three" class="home-grid"> <div class="page" title="Page 2"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the markup or try FIDDLE the scenario.

Comment: added the markup sorry there is quiet abit

Comment: Sidenote: You're using the `jQuery` identifier in some places and `$` in others. Consistency is key.

Comment: @George thanks for the tip

Comment: combine on click and mouse leave events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of jquery click event are as below

```
jQuery(".leftpara").click(function(){
  //do something here
});
```

or

```
jQuery(".leftpara").on("click",function(){
  //do something here
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".leftpara",function(){
   //do something here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, would the same work with .off instead of mouseleave?

Comment: jQuery(".leftpara")on("click",function(){ you forgot a . here

Comment: @Joe I believe its not because .off will remove event handlers that were attached using .on(). I also think you can leave mouseleave as it is after a user click something then you do something in that click event, then he points the cursor to other element, mouseleave would trigger.

Comment: @Rickdep
Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the desired effect by adding a counter in each function. I first off initialize the counter variable and then in the click trigger I add one. I then have an IF statement so when the clicks reach 2 it changes the values back to default and resets the counter. Below is an example

```
(function() {
  var count = 0;

  jQuery('#home-grid-one-two').click(function () {
    count += 1;
    jQuery('#home-grid-two-one').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-two-three').hide();
jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').css('background-image',   'url("A PICTURE")');
jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').css({
        'background-size': 'cover' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-three-three').hide();
jQuery('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'margin-top': '-450px' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').css({
        'margin-top': '-420px' 
    });
jQuery(".leftpara").show();
jQuery(".rightpara").show();
jQuery(".ptagexp").hide();


    if (count == 2) {
     jQuery('#home-grid-two-one').css({
        'visibility': 'visible' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'visibility': 'visible' 
    });
    jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').show();
    jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').css('background-image',   'none');
    jQuery('#home-grid-two-two').css({
        'margin-top': '0px' 
    });
jQuery('#home-grid-three-two').css({
        'margin-top': '0px' 
    });
            jQuery('#home-grid-two-one').show();
            jQuery('#home-grid-three-one').show();
            jQuery('#home-grid-two-three').show();
            jQuery('#home-grid-three-three').show();
jQuery(".leftpara").hide();
jQuery(".rightpara").hide();
jQuery(".ptagexp").show();
count = 0;
    }
  });
})();
```